# How to change amount of DELIVERY_ATTEMPT before fail in KafkaListener?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Lets say I have the following listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${some_topic}", autoStartup = "true")
public void listenForMessage(String message) {          
    log.warn("Accepted message"); 
    if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("some error");
        } 

}
```

I try to send message to the topic `${some_topic}` and see following:

```
2023-06-15 10:00:03.311  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.381  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.399  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.414  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.430  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.445  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.460  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message 
2023-06-15 10:00:03.477  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.492  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.509  WARN 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] r.v.u.e.s.MyServiceImpl               : Accepted message
2023-06-15 10:00:03.509 ERROR 33580 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.FallbackBatchErrorHandler        : Records discarded: my-topic-0@33

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.****.listenForMessage(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: some error; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Ololo
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2871) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2407) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2377) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$invokeBatchErrorHandler$46(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2419) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandlingUtils.retryBatch(ErrorHandlingUtils.java:185) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FallbackBatchErrorHandler.handle(FallbackBatchErrorHandler.java:131) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandlerAdapter.handleBatch(ErrorHandlerAdapter.java:160) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedBatchProcessor.fallback(FailedBatchProcessor.java:191) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedBatchProcessor.handle(FailedBatchProcessor.java:159) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedBatchProcessor.doHandle(FailedBatchProcessor.java:150) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleBatch(DefaultErrorHandler.java:182) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2417) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2234) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2095) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2074) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1429) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1393) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1290) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
    Suppressed: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Restored Stack Trace
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:363) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invoke(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:180) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:172) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2387) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: some error
    at ***(MyServiceImpl.java:59) ~[classes/:?]
    at ***.listenForMessage(MyServiceImpl.java:39) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:339) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invoke(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:180) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:172) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2387) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
```

We see that listener tries to accept message 10 times and after fail #10 it prints error (and sends ack as far as I understand). I wanted to play with that behaviout

I tried to implement following errorHandler to decrease retry amount to 3:

```
   @Bean
    public KafkaListenerErrorHandler eh() {
        return (msg, ex) -> {
            if (msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT, Integer.class) > 3) {
                return "FAILED";
            }
            throw ex;
        };
    }
```

and reference to it

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${some_topic}", autoStartup = "true", errorHandler = "eh")
public void listenForMessage(String message) {          
    log.warn("Accepted message"); 
    if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("some error");
        } 

}
```

But `msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT, Integer.class)` throws exception. So the behaviour is the same: 10 attempts to accept and then I see exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.get(Object, java.lang.Class)" is null
```

As far I understand there is a way to mark some exceptions retriable and some - not. Could you please provide example of configuration ?

Comment: Official docs have everything. Check here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#after-rollback. Search for "By default, after ten failures, the failed record is logged..." and "You can add more exception types to the not-retryable category." The DELIVERY_ATTEMPT header doesn't work because you need to enable it - set the container property deliveryAttemptHeader to true (check here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#delivery-header)

Comment: @Dmitrii Bocharov could you please provide example of code how to do it ?
```
To enable population of this header, set the container property deliveryAttemptHeader to true. It is disabled by default to avoid the (small) overhead of looking up the state for each record and adding the header.
```

Comment: Or maybe something should be added to application.properties ?

Comment: See my answer - you just need to change the default back off in the `DefaultErrorHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

Add a `DefaultErrorHandler` with a different `FixedBackOff` (the default is 9 retries with no back off between attempts).

```java
DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler =
    new DefaultErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
        // recover after 3 failures, with no back off - e.g. send to a dead-letter topic
    }, new FixedBackOff(0L, 2L));
```

You have to enable the delivery attempts header, it is not enabled by default.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#delivery-header

Comment: I tried to enable this header but no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76481597/messagehandlingexception-missing-header-kafka-deliveryattempt-for-method-para

Comment: I just answered that - you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: retry behaviour works

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the comments + adding the example

The `DELIVERY_ATTEMPT` header doesn't work because you need to enable it - set the container property deliveryAttemptHeader to true (check here docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#delivery-header). You need to create a `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
                        kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

Check an example of the rest of the beans (e.g. consumerFactory()) here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#record-listener.  And then in the listener, you do:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "${some_topic}", autoStartup = "true", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
```

And of course, also check the answer by Gary Russell

Comment: Thank you, @Dmitrii! But looks like spring boot creates those beans instead of me and I just need to customize bean.

Comment: You're welcome! True. I just posted in this answer how you can enable the `DELIVERY_ATTEMPT  `header by `factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);`. That's what you asked in the comments of the question